# Algorithms used for Bundle Making problem

Tags: algorithm

Given a set A of items that we can collect, and B ⊆ A of items we have collected and a list of bundles where the definition of a bundle is (C, k) with k <= |C| and C ⊆ A. (C, k) means we have to collect k elements of C to make a bundle. I am a little be confused what algorithm can be used to solve such a problem by finding minimum set D ⊆ A\B such that we can make all bundles? (I just need some hints about how to transform the problem to related algorithmatic problems)

Comment: can adding one item from A to B help us build 2 or more bundles? I think you should give a few examples if possible

Comment: if we collect more than `k` elements of `C` does it still makes a bundle?

Comment: For now for me it looks like another formulation of integer programming which can't be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  "I need some hints" says that you're asking on the wrong site -- Stack Overflow is specifically *not* a site for personalized help in problem decomposition.

Comment: U r not so humanized and friendly. Firstly, I thank those who shared their ideas with me. Then, to my perspective, stackoverflow is a place to share idea, knowledge and thoughts. I am not here to seek answer from my question and I don’t need that as well. I just want to discuss the question with people who is willing to share their ideas. I posted question here it does not mean I don’t work hard or I don’t put effort to think about this question, and in fact I did figure it out by myself. Finally, very appreciate those who shared their ide.

Comment: For the question, here is my idea. In fact, we can use network flow algorithms to solve it, possibly. We can transform the question to a graph question, and add source and sink vertices to the graph so that we can use network flow method. Nodes in the graph means A, and those items we have already collected (B) are connected to sink vertices while the rest of vertices in A connect to source vertex. Then we need to remove k nodes from A excluding nodes in B that makes the graph disconnected, the removed nodes form the set of items that makes bundle.